# No4j create different edge based on property

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to add a second edge but with the same relationship name between the two nodes as the properties are different. But I am seeing only one edge and properties related to that edge.

For example, I have two rows in CSV with 5 columns shown below

start stop service    code    usage

340   350   Fixed    Main     Less

340   350   Fixed    Second   High

The query I am using to create the database is as follows
load CSV file cypher syntax

```
create e node with service as a property
create s note with start and stop as property
MERGE (e)-[r:INCLUDED_IN]->(s)
SET r.Usage=aloc.usage, r.Code=aloc.code
```

The resultant output is two nodes with first-row parameters and a single relationship. I expect two edges as relationship properties in the second row are different. It is not showing second-row properties and relationships.

Is there any way to model this correctly?
Regards
Vaishali

I am expecting two edges between two nodes. It is showing only one edge with first-row properties. Second-row properties are not shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the properties after the `MERGE` statement, that's why it's overriding the previous relation, set the properties in the merge like this:

```
create e node with service as a property
create s note with start and stop as property
MERGE (e)-[r:INCLUDED_IN{Usage: aloc.usage, Code: aloc.code}]->(s)
```

Comment: I resolved this with the same logic. Neo4j community replied on that day itself